# Failure in holding session

Tags: php, session

I am trying to create a register and login page using php mysqli on submitting both forms user is redirected to `main.php` where header menu has home, inbox etc menus, but in case a users who are not logged in visit `main.php` they will see sign up and login menus. But here my `header.php` does not recognize session. On having a logged in user header menu should change to home, inbox etc but after logging in it still shows sign up login menus.

`register.php`

```
 <?php include ( "./inc/header.inc.php" ); ?>
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","findfriends") or die ("Connection not established");
  ?>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
  session_start(); 
  $fn=strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
  $ln=strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
  $un=strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
  $em=strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
  $pswd=strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
  $d= date("Y-m-d");
  $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO users (userid,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,sign_up_date,activated,bio,profile_photo,closed) VALUES ('','{$un}','{$fn}','{$ln}','{$em}','{$pswd}','{$d}','0','What you do?','','no')");
   }
   ?>
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $em = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '',$_POST["email"]); // fill everything but numbers and letters
    $pswd = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '',$_POST["password"]); // fill everything but numbers and letters
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$em' AND password='$pswd'");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
    } 
    ?>

   <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td width="60%" valign="top">
   <h2>Already a member? Login Below</h2>
   <form action="main.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="user_login" size="25" placeholder="UserName"/><br><br>
      <input type="password" name="password_login" size="30" placeholder="Passsword"/><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
    </td>
    <td width="40%" valign="top">
    <h2>Sign Up!</h2>
    <form action="main.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="fname" size="25" placeholder="First Name"/> 
      <input type="text" name="lname" size="25" placeholder="Last Name"/><br><br>
      <input type="text" name="username" size="25" placeholder="Username"/><br><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" size="25" placeholder="Email"/><br><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" size="25" placeholder="Password"/><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
      </form>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

`header.php`

```
   <?php
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","findfriends") or die ("Connection not established");
    ?>
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }
     else {
    $user = "";
    }
     ?>

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
       <head>
       <title>findfriends</title>
       <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div class="headerMenu">
       <div id="wrapper">
       <div class="logo">
       <img src="./img/logo.gif"/>
       </div>
       <div class="search_box">
       <form action="searchresults.php" method="post" name="search">
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td>  
       <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search ..."/>
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="image" src="./img/search-icon.png" alt="submit" />
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
       </div>
       <div class="cb">
       <a href="create_blog.php">Create a Blog</a>
       </div>

      <?php
       if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        echo '
        <ul class="dd">
        <li><a href="main.php" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="' . $user . '">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="my_messages.php">Inbox' . $unread_numrows . '</a>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="#">Management</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="account_settings.php">Settings</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a> 
        </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>';
        }
        else
        {
        echo '
        <ul class="dd">
        <li><a href="register.php" >Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="register.php">Login</a>
        </li>
        </ul>';
         }
         ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: why do you have  `session_start();` twice in a single file?

Comment: ok i deleted that second session but whats problem in this code anyone please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it,  in your `header.php` `if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))` is always false. You should have a better approach on how to do this. Something like:

Since you have two scenarios where a session (or maybe cookie) could be used/set i.e.

**(1)** When a user registers/sign up.

**(2)** When a user logins/sign in.

For scenario **(1).**

After you have your query which `INSERTs` the new record in the database. Use a `session` or I'd prefer set a `cookie` to store the user information and redirect him/her to the `main.php`

An example:

```
$reg_query = "INSERT INTO signup(First_Name, Last_Name, Gender)
 VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$gender')";
$reg_run = mysqli_query($con, $reg_query);
        $Month = 86400 + time(); 
     setcookie('user', $uname, $Month);  
      echo "The cookie has been set."; 

header("Location:main.php");
```

For scenario **(2).**

After the successful check/match that a user is already registered. Set a cookie and move him/her to the `main.php`

An example:

```
$log_que = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass' ";
$log_run = mysqli_query($con, $log_que);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($log_run);
$user_db = $log_row['username'];
$pass_db = $log_row['password'];

if($user == $user_db && $pass == $pass_db)
{
    echo "LOGGED IN!"; 
     $Month = 86400 + time(); 
     setcookie('user', $user, $Month); 
      header("Location:main.php");
}
```

And Now, on your `main.php` you should have checks applied like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
        echo '<nav id = "navigation">
    <ul>
         <li><a href = "welcome.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href = "index.php">View</a></li>
         <li><a href = "myprofile.php">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id = "line"></div>';
}
else
{
echo '<nav id = "navigation">
    <ul>
         <li><a href = "welcome.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href = "index.php">View</a></li>
         <li><a href = "login.php">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href = "signup.php">Signup</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id = "line"></div>';
}   
?>
```

Last but not the least, on your `signout.php` dont forget to propery unset(); them. An example:

```
<?php         

if(isset($_COOKIE['user']))
          {  
            unset($_COOKIE['user']); 
            setcookie('user', '', time() - 3600, 'login.php');
            setcookie('user', '', time() - 3600, 'signup.php');
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('YOU HAVE LOGGED OUT!')</script>";
          }
         header("refresh:1; url=welcomepage.php");
?>
```

> Notice: Study mysqli/PDO along with how to avoid SQL Injection/XSS.
>   And If you're using sessions. Just replace the cookies with sessions
>   and properly unset/destroy them on signout page.

Comment: thnks for help bro but still not working my login code is `<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])){ $log_que = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pswd' "; $log_run = mysqli_query($con, $log_que); $row = mysql_fetch_array($log_run); $un_db = $log_row['username']; $pswd_db = $log_row['password']; if($un == $un_db && $pswd == $pswd_db) { echo "LOGGED IN!"; setcookie('user',$uname,time()+3600*24*365); header("Location:main.php"); } } ?>` using main.php exactly the same as you did.

Comment: @Harman where are you getting '$un' and '$pswd' after the if statement? Further more, you are using the deprecated 'mysql_fetch_array();' change it to 'mysqli_fetch_array();' instead.

Comment: `$un` and `$pswd` are variables i use to insert data into users table in sign up page it is up in question as well ,so is this the problem?, Previously i used single page for sign up and login but now i am using separate pages , and sorry changed that to mysqli as well

Comment: @Harman change the action = "" to empty or write the above posted php in main.php. As soon as you press the submit button it takes you to the main.php and hence doesn't run the php written above.

Comment: thnks brother everything is working fine now, but when i enter wrong password in login form browser pops up remember password before user is redirected to main.php i guess it has nothing to do with code?